# Wordpress admin panel stop updating the options?

Tags: wordpress

Good Evening,

I am working on wordpress website http://browsewire.net which was working well few days back, But now I am facing following issues:

1. Trying to update posts, widgets and uploading images to media directory but the process stop at a blank page without updating anything.
2. Widget's drag drop is working but do nothing save in options table.

I have updated my wordpress installation to recent version. Kindly guide me how can I fix it, as I checked my console and found nothing like error.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in function.php

```
 add_action( 'init', create_function( '$a', "remove_action( 'init', 'wp_version_check' );" ), 2 );
 add_filter( 'pre_option_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
```